# Row is not updating in gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am using update commandField in Gridview. the Textbox used in gridview returning old value. the code for this.

```
string id = ((Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Label6")).Text;
        string name = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
        string number = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox2")).Text;
        string mail = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox3")).Text;
        string address = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox4")).Text;
        string s = "update contacts set c_name='"+name+"', c_number='"+number+"', c_mail = '"+mail+"', c_address = '"+address+"' where contact_id = "+id+"";
        getsqlConnection();
        dbConnection.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(s, dbConnection);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        loadcontacts();
```

Please Help...

Comment: I can't see any Update command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [updating data into gridview in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075882/updating-data-into-gridview-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
}
```

This code at `Page Load` solved my problem.